# Swift: Could not build Objective-C module when using CocoaPods

Tags: swift, xcode6, cocoapods

I just started working on a project in Xcode using Swift, and I soon figured out that using CocoaPods can help a lot in managing external frameworks.

I just installed CocoaPods as described on their website, and I added two pods: ObjectMapper and SwiftyJSON. In one of my .swift files I am importing the ObjectMapper (`import ObjectMapper`).

When I build the project, it gives me the following error:

```
could not build Objective-C module 'ObjectMapper'
```

I already tried reinstalling CocoaPods and creating a Bridging Header, but unfortunately neither of them worked.
When I create a Bridging Header (as described here: http://michal.codes/integrating-cocoapods-with-a-swift-project/), it tells me it can't find ObjectMapper.h)

Maybe I am doing something wrong, but since I am totally new to this, I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

What am I doing wrong?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you actually have the swift files in your pod project? Swift support is currently experimental in cocoapods ithink.

Comment: Yes, I just installed the pods in terminal and they appear in Xcode under the 'Pods' section

Comment: Try to build first ObjectMapper in your xcode workspace. If it's OK, come back to your main project then build.

Comment: You should not import `ObjectMapper` into your actual swift file. Swift auto imports. You only need to import it into your bridging header.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. How should I place it in the bridging header? Can you please post an answer?

Comment: Done. Hopefully it is good enough but given my experience there may still be some issues. Let me know if you have any further problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was a bit mistaken in my previous answer. After doing a bit more research I found that both of these pods you are attempting to use are Swift file based so there is no need to use a bridging header (at least for these pods).

You want to setup your Podfile like this:

```
use_frameworks!

pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.1'
pod 'ObjectMapper', '~> 0.9'
```

or some variant, but the key part being the `use_frameworks!` flag.

Now this is where I was mistake before. Given that these are Swift based libraries now you will need to import then into your Swift files like you were attempting to before (`import SwiftJSON`). Then you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! ObjectMapper also contains Swift Files only, but when I remove `import ObjectMapper`, I get a lot of errors because some classes can not be found. When I try your solution, I got the error that it can not find `ObjectMapper.h`

Comment: If `ObjectMapper` includes Swift files you may not need to import it anywhere at all (like you normally do nothing with your local swift files). Try that. Otherwise I'll create a project and see what is going on. I am guessing it includes a `.h` to easily access it in Obj-C.

Comment: The Swift files from `ObjectMapper` are just in the Pods project map. As you can see in the screenshot, my own code is not able to find the classes from `ObjectMapper`. http://nl.tinypic.com/r/2lnz3nm/8

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I already had `use_frameworks!` in my Pod file, but I still get the error given in my initial question...

Comment: There must be something else going on then. Working on an empty project this worked for me. You could try creating a test project to see if you can spot any differences.

Comment: I can not spot any difference with my project and a test project. It keeps giving me the error. If I delete the pod 'ObjectMapper' from the PodFile, I still get the error. Maybe important to notice: I first used the ObjectMapper as a submodule in git

Comment: I recreated the entire project, and now it works. I still don't now what went wrong

Comment: Well I am glad it is working now. Very likely there were remnants of the submodule left somewhere in the project settings and that was confusing the projects build. Just thankful it is fine now!